# Font family automatically changes to "undefined,sans-serif!important" in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

Recently, when I am using google chrome's developer tools, the default font-family is automatically being changed to "undefined, sans-serif" with the "!important" tag attached.  So unless I add an inline style using the "!important" tag, it ignores my font family style rules.  Has anyone experienced this?

I've provided a screenshot via the URL below and the URL to the actual HTML page.  The reason the code is so messy is because I'm designing this to be sent through Outlook 2007 (if you know what that's all about).

**Screenshot:**
http://preview.fahlgrengrip.com/pcb/epro-email/april/img/chrome-bug.jpg

**HTML**
http://preview.fahlgrengrip.com/pcb/epro-email/april/

Comment: You seem to be using the `font` tag, which is deprecated in HTML 4 and obsolete in HTML 5.

Comment: The font tag is obsolete, but their are instances when it is useful in trying to get outlook to render correctly.  Removing the font tags was not a fix for this issue.

Comment: @Matt He/She hasn't specified a doctype.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I had a font style extension installed that I didn't know about.  After I uninstalled that, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It has been crossed out, which means it has been overwritten by something else.